# explode() on multiple delimiters

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to explode() with multiple delimiters.

With the delimiters:

- "&"
- " and "
- "/"
- ","

**So that, for example if I have this array:**

```
<?php
    $lol = array(
        "Strawberry/Blueberry/Raspberry",
        "Strawberry, Blueberry, Raspberry",
        "Strawberry & Blueberry & Raspberry",
        "Strawberry and Blueberry and Raspberry",
        "Strawberry, Blueberry and Raspberry",
        "Strawberry, Blueberry, Raspberry",
    );
?>
```

**It would output this:**

```
<?php
    $lol = array(
        array("Strawberry","Blueberry","Raspberry"),
        array("Strawberry","Blueberry","Raspberry"),
        array("Strawberry","Blueberry","Raspberry"),
        array("Strawberry","Blueberry","Raspberry"),
        array("Strawberry","Blueberry","Raspberry"),
        array("Strawberry","Blueberry","Raspberry"),
    );
?>
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($lol);$i++){
    $lol[$i] = preg_split("@(\s*and\s*)?[/\s,&]+@", $lol[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the delimiters to a common that `explode()` will accept:

```
foreach($lol as $key => $current) {
    $bits = explode(',', stri_replace(array('/', '&', 'and'), ',', $current));
    $lol[$key] = $bits;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_split()` - then you use a regular expression to say "a or b or c"

Sample:

```
<?php
    $lol = array(
        "Strawberry/Blueberry/Raspberry",
        "Strawberry, Blueberry, Raspberry",
        "Strawberry & Blueberry & Raspberry",
        "Strawberry and Blueberry and Raspberry",
        "Strawberry, Blueberry and Raspberry",
        "Strawberry, Blueberry, Raspberry",
    );
    $s = "/\/|, | & | and /";
    foreach ($lol as $v) {
      print_r(preg_split($s, $v));
    }
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Strawberry
    [1] => Blueberry
    [2] => Raspberry
)
Array
(
    [0] => Strawberry
    [1] => Blueberry
    [2] => Raspberry
)
Array
(
    [0] => Strawberry
    [1] => Blueberry
    [2] => Raspberry
)
Array
(
    [0] => Strawberry
    [1] => Blueberry
    [2] => Raspberry
)
Array
(
    [0] => Strawberry
    [1] => Blueberry
    [2] => Raspberry
)
Array
(
    [0] => Strawberry
    [1] => Blueberry
    [2] => Raspberry
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_split`:

```
$arr = preg_split('~ *(?:[/,&]|and) */i~', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<?php
    $lol = array(
        "Strawberry/Blueberry/Raspberry",
        "Strawberry, Blueberry, Raspberry",
        "Strawberry & Blueberry & Raspberry",
        "Strawberry and Blueberry and Raspberry",
        "Strawberry, Blueberry and Raspberry",
        "Strawberry, Blueberry, Raspberry",
    );
for($i=0;$i<count($lol);$i++){
$tem=str_ireplace("&",",",str_ireplace("/",",",str_ireplace("and",",",$lol[$i])));//first replacing all (& , / , and) with "," then explod with ","
$lol[$i]=explode(",",$tem);}
```